# Is x=; and if(d<) invalid to use in c language

Tags: c, syntax-error, bgi

At the end of this question there is Mid-Point circle drawing algorithm in c language. I saw the following two statements in the code

> x=;
>
> if(d<);

in the program online and in our book as well, so basically i thought that the compiler might automatically be initializing them to 0(zero) so i wrote the same code in our homework. But the teacher said that it is wrong and indeed it gives **Invalid Expression** in **Turbo C++** compiler. Thats why I want to know if it is wrong then why is it written like this everywhere.

Here is the code :

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
   int gd=DETECT,gm;
   int i,r,x,y,xc,yc;
   float d;

   clrscr();

   initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\tc\\");

   printf("Enter Radius\n");
   scanf("%d",&r);

   printf("Enter Center of circle\n");
   scanf("%d",&xc);
   scanf("%d",&yc);

   d=1.25-r;
   x=;
   y=r;
   do {
        if(d<) {
            x=x+1;
            d=d+2*x+1;
        }  else {
               x=x+1;
               y=y-1;
              d=d+2*x-2*y+10;
       }
       putpixel(xc+x,yc+y,5);
       putpixel(xc-y,yc-x,5);
       putpixel(xc+y,yc-x,5);
       putpixel(xc-y,yc+x,5);
       putpixel(xc+y,yc+x,5);
       putpixel(xc-x,yc-y,5);
       putpixel(xc+x,yc-y,5);
       putpixel(xc-x,yc+y,5);
    } while(x<y);
    getch();
}
```

Also it is the link of above code:

[Mid Point Circle Drawing Algorithm Code in c Language](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://programcodelib.com/2012/08/c-program-for-drawing-a-circle-using-midpoint-circle-algorithm/&ei=oz7Rkxap&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=601&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1486398737&sig=AJsQQ1DllPd82toKIwwRpdSkOiQUZ4CiXQ)

Please help me out.  Thanks.

Comment: If you saw code like that anywhere, it's wrong. It's not how C works. And what you do mean with "written like this everywhere"? I've never seen expressions like that except as examples of non-working code.

Comment: You need (a) a good book on whatever *language* you're actually intending on using (pick one; C **or** C++), and (b) a toolchain made sometime in the last decade or so.

Comment: The compiler doesn't initialize the variable in the "function scope". They're initialized if you declare it as static variable. I suggest you to always initialize the variable to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: This syntax is wrong, you can try to confirm it yourself using http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf.

Comment: There are typos in your book (it's quite common), and probably someone has reproduced those exactly online by typing in the book's code in the hope of getting some advertising hits.

Comment: Umm... Well i guess it is wrong then. Thanx a lt guys.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the link is give at the bottom of the question

Comment: Looks like what happened is the author put the code through some formatter that picked out < being part of html but could not find the > and wiped all the code until the ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ques.** What is storage class of variable x?

**ans.**   local variables i.e. **var x** used in a block statement( as you used inside the main() ) is belong to "AUTO" storage class in C.

**One More Ques** **:-**
Now, question arises in you mind that, what is the default value with ,auto variable initialised with**??**

**Ans.**  Initialized with "*Garbage Value*".

In declaration of x:-

```
int i,r,x,y,xc,yc;
```

*Note:-*   **x is initialized with garbage value**.

but you write,

```
x=;
```

**Note:-** which is niether the declaration nor the initilaization statement,
                                                                   but it is the **Incomplete statement**  which'll not understand by the compilor so it gives the error  :
                      **Invalid Expression**

Now, come to your next doubt:-

```
if(d<);
```

**it's also a invalid expresion because just think in general maths if you compute:-
            if  2 is greater than ______??**

*can you imagine the value in blank space??
 yes, you can but, compilor(or computer) can'not  :)*

Comment: thanx bro for the accept the solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 5):

No, those expressions are not syntactically valid.

Books have typos, and fishy-looking reproductions of books online also have typos. That image looks like a cell phone photo or something, really dubious.

Just because something is said online, it doesn't have to be true<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Said an anonymous stranger online. :)

Comment: the footnote alone is worth +1

Answer (score 1):

The code on the link you provided has obviously been mutilated.

The correct code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
  int gd = DETECT, gm;
  int r, x, y, p, xc = 320, yc = 240;

  initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
  cleardevice();    

  printf("Enter the radius ");
  scanf("%d", &r);    

  x = 0;
  y = r;
  putpixel(xc + x, yc - y, 1);

  p = 3 - (2 * r);

  for (x = 0; x <= y; x++)
  {
    if (p<0)
    {
      y = y;
      p = (p + (4 * x) + 6);
    }
    else
    {
      y = y - 1;    
      p = p + ((4 * (x - y) + 10));
    }

    putpixel(xc + x, yc - y, 1);
    putpixel(xc - x, yc - y, 2);
    putpixel(xc + x, yc + y, 3);
    putpixel(xc - x, yc + y, 4);
    putpixel(xc + y, yc - x, 5);
    putpixel(xc - y, yc - x, 6);
    putpixel(xc + y, yc + x, 7);
    putpixel(xc - y, yc + x, 8);    
  }

  getch();
  closegraph();
}
```

Note: this code as it stands here works only on the antique Turbo C. For other platforms adaptions need to be made.